# How does the promise then works?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I am trying to print all asynchronous calls in a sequence using promise. But i didn't understand whether then implicitly returns a promise or we should explicitly return it.

```
 function fakeAjax(url,cb) {
        var fake_responses = {
          "file1": "The first text",
            "file2": "The middle text",
            "file3": "The last text"
        };
        var randomDelay = (Math.round(Math.random() * 1E4) % 8000) + 1000;

        console.log("Requesting: " + url);

        setTimeout(function(){
            cb(fake_responses[url]);
        },randomDelay);
    }

    function output(text) {
        console.log(text);
    }

    // **************************************

    function getFile(file) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
            fakeAjax(file,resolve);
        })
    };


    let p1= getFile('file1');
    let p2= getFile('file2');
    let p3= getFile('file3');
    p1.then(output)  // how does this code work? output doesn't return any promise, but  still we can chain it with next .then()
    .then( ()=> p2)
    .then(output)
    .then(()=>p3)
    .then(output)
    .then(()=>output('complete'))
```

Comment: `then` returns a promise enabling you to chain the functions that way. It implicitly converts takes the return value of `output` as the next `resolution`, and then makes it available in next `then`. In your case, it will be `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

`then` returns a promise enabling you to chain the functions that way. It implicitly converts takes the return value of `output` as the next *resolution*, and then makes it available in next then. In your case, it will be `undefined`.

Below is slight modification of your snippet, where I'm showing how `then` can enable you to create new `Promise` on the fly based on return value of last promise's resolution.

Here, in `output` method, after `console.log`, I have returned the value. Try running the snippet to see it in action.

```js
function fakeAjax (url, cb) {
  var fake_responses = {
    'file1': 'file2',
    'file2': 'file3',
    'file3': 'The last text'
  }
  var randomDelay = 500

  console.log('Requesting: ' + url)

  setTimeout(function () {
    cb(fake_responses[url])
  }, randomDelay)
}

function output (text) {
  console.log(text)
  return text; // return the value
}

// **************************************

function getFile (file) {
  console.log('creating prommise for', file)
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fakeAjax(file, resolve)
  })
}

var p1 = getFile('file1')
p1.then(output)
  .then(getFile)
  .then(output)
  .then(getFile)
  .then(output)
```

From the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then):

> The then() method returns a Promise. It takes up to two arguments: callback functions for the success and failure cases of the Promise.
>
> If one or both arguments are omitted or are provided non-functions, then then will be missing the handler(s), but will not generate any errors. If the Promise that then is called on adopts a state (fulfillment or rejection) for which then has no handler, a new Promise is created with no additional handlers, simply adopting the final state of the original Promise on which then was called.